# CSS3 disappears after keyframe animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm using css3 to animate some text. I'm just trying to fade it in, and then disappear only to do it again a few seconds later (after other animations). The problem i'm having is my text fades in but immediately disappears even though i have the keyframe finish @ opacity:1; Why is my text disappearing? Here's the code:

```
<style>
#myArea {
   height:250px;
   width:300px;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.text {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  bottom:20px; 
  left:10px;
  opacity:1;

}

#txt1 {
  animation: txt1-fade 1s 1 ease-in;
  animation-delay:1s;
}

#txt2 {
  -webkit-animation: txt2-fade 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: txt2-fade 5s infinite;
}

#txt3 {
  -webkit-animation: txt3-fade 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: txt3-fade 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes txt1-fade {
    0%   {opacity: 0; left:10px;}
    100% {opacity: 1; left:10px;}
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="myArea">

<img src="images/backgrnd.jpg" />

<div id="txt1" class="text">
<img src="images/text1.png" />
</div>

<div id="txt2" class="text">
<img src="images/text2.png" />
</div>

<div id="txt3" class="text">
<img src="images/text3.png" />
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By default elements return to their original state after an animation is completed. You can keep the state in which the element is in at end of animation by applying `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp

Comment: sweet! is there a way i could "say" after this animation is done, do this other animation and so on and so forth?

Comment: You can listen for animationend event using JavaScript and trigger the next animation when pervious one ends

Comment: You can also use Web Animations to do it. It makes grouping animations very easy but it not supported in most browsers yet so you'll need to use a polyfill https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/simplified-concepts-in-web-animations-naming?hl=en

Comment: great solution!